# How to read specific zip file data stored in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, zip, hdfs

Assume i have a Zip file called **Sample.zip** stored in **HDFS**. It is having the following files **sample1.txt**, **sample2.txt**, **sample3.txt** etc.. 

Now my requirement is if i pass file called sample2.txt i want to read the sample2.txt file data only.

I have code to read entire zip file data. [Java Code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39444392/1918962)

Please let me know is there any way to read the specific file data from the zip file.

Comment: Why don'y you just traverse through the zipentries by calling getNextEntry() and if the name of the entry does not match the desired one, close the entry by calling closeEntry(). Just process, when you get the stream to be pointed at the desired entry

Comment: I did that one but i want to do it in hdfs side without traversing.